# MYSQL Index as a variable in a query

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I'm trying to get a criteria from 2 Columns and indexing them using this query

```
$query1 = "SET @row_num = 0";
$query2 = "SELECT *, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index FROM gift 
           WHERE Category = '0' AND ID ='".$ID."'
           ORDER BY ID ASC;";
mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

$retrieve = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
```

Is there is a way in which I can use the row_index as a variable in the query, like this:

```
$query1 = "SET @row_num = 0";
$query2 = "SELECT *, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index FROM gift
           WHERE Category = '0' AND row_index ='".$ID."'
           ORDER BY ID ASC;";
mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

$retrieve = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
```

Comment: the variable @row_num is used to increment each row of the row_index column by 1.

Comment: `row_index=@row_num`?

Comment: can you give a sample what you expected please

Comment: You can the alias in a HAVING clause `WHERE....HAVING row_index = $ID` You really don't need the concatenation and if `$ID` is alpha-numeric you only need to quote it.

Comment: yes, each row of row_index has a value greater by one than the previous row. @row_num is a variable than increments the row_index column by one in each row for the given query. the thing is row_index is not a pre-defined column in the DB, it changes per query or reload, so I'm not able to call it as in the second piece of code.

Comment: `FROM gift cross join (select @row_num = 0) n`

Comment: From what I can tell, you want to pull the `$ID`th row from the result set. If this is correct, just use `LIMIT $ID,1` and get rid of all the row_index stuff

Comment: `$ID` appears to be set outside of the query @Steve but since the OP hasn't responded it is hard to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys but @JayBlanchard answer solved my problem.

Comment: since an answer has been given below, I think it's only fair that @JayBlanchard transforms his comment as an answer in order to mark the question as solved. Edit: Ah, I see he has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for the `$ID` in a `HAVING` clause:

```
$query1 = "SET @row_num = 0";
$query2 = "SELECT *, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index FROM gift
           WHERE Category = '0' 
           HAVING row_index = $ID
           ORDER BY ID ASC;";
mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

$retrieve = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
```

There is no need to concatenate the variable in the query. If `$ID` is an integer there is no need for quotes and if it is alpha-numeric just enclose it in single-quotes as PHP will interpolate the variable correctly.

---

[Reference for HAVING clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Glad to help @user6645308

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually having tested it, I would expect something like the following to work....

```
SELECT ilv.*
FROM (
   SELECT gift.*, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index 
   FROM gift
   WHERE Category = '0' 
   ORDER BY ID ASC
) ilv
WHERE row_index ='".$ID."';
```

(but you shouldn't be quoting an integer value).

Or....

```
SELECT *
FROM gift
WHERE Category = '0' 
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT $ID, 1;
```

Or, with a recent MySQL, using the MyISAM engine, you can [define a primary key based on a natural key and autoincrement value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). In your case, the "natural" key would be category. Then if you ensure that you are allocating the id *stored* in the database at a monotonic interval and simply.....

```
SELECT *
FROM gift
WHERE category='0'
AND id=($ID * $interval);
```